# Is data cached on server or client or not at all in AngularJS when an error occurs in a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, caching

Keep in mind, I'm running an old version of AngularJS (1.0?), so things may have changed, but I have code that looks like:

```
promise = $http.get(urlFormattedString).success(function (data) {
                                data.forEach(function (result) {
                                    //do something with result and $scope});

promises.push(promise);
$q.all(promises).then(function (data) {
//do something good when everything works!
};
```

When no errors are thrown, everything "works", but my question is what happens when one of the promises throws an error (say 1 out of 20)? Let's make this more interesting (and closer to my application) and assume that each promise is requesting data from a database (MongoDB in my case).

If I have to re-run everything, does that mean necessarily that all the data needs to be fetched again? Am I relying on the database to cache the data so the repeated requests run much faster? Or maybe the server (NodeJS in my case) caches the data? Along these lines, when are the data actually sent to the client from the server? Is it only upon success of all promises or is the data returned to the client from each promise separately? And if so, does Angular do the caching?

Just laying this out here makes me realize this is pretty complex and lots of scenarios to consider. Would appreciate any help or pointers to reading/documentation on this subject. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you familiarize yourself with the network tab of your browser dev tools.

You can see every request made for all resources from html to images to scripts as well as ajax requests. This will give you a far better feel for how the app works in general

As for errors ... unless you implement error handling your app will simply fail for that request with no indication given to user that anything went wrong.

As for caching ... your ajax requests won't be cached client side and unless you have implemented caching mechaanisms on server they won't be cached there either